# HP 2510G Loop Protect doesn't work

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, switch

I have a problem with Loop-Protect on a HP 2510G Switch.

I configured Loop-Protect with `loop-protect all receiver-action send-disable` and set `transmit-interval 1` and `disable-timer 30`.

I tested my setup: 
Client 1 at Port 1 ping Client 2 at Port 2. 
Then I directly connected Ports 3 and 4 with a patch-cable. 
The most times the Loop was detectet and Port 3 and 4 go down. 
2 of 14 Loops are never detected and the Network will be flooded.

What could be the error?

Here is the output of `show loop-protect`:

```
ProCurve Switch 2510G-48# show loop-protect 

 Status and Counters - Loop Protection Information

 Transmit Interval (sec)  : 1           
 Port Disable Timer (sec) : 30          
 Loop Detected Trap       : Disabled    


       Loop        Loop      Loop       Time             Rx           Port   
  Port Protection  Detected  Count      Since Last Loop  Action       Status  
  ---- ----------- --------- ---------- ---------------- ------------ --------
  1    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  2    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  3    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  4    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  5    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  6    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  7    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  8    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  9    Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  10   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  11   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  12   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  13   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  14   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  15   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  16   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  17   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  18   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  19   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  20   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  21   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  22   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  23   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  24   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  25   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  26   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  27   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  28   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  29   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  30   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  31   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  32   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  33   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  34   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  35   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  36   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  37   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  38   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  39   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  40   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  41   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  42   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  43   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  44   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  45   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  46   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  47   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
  48   Yes         No        0                           send-disable Down    
ProCurve Switch 2510G-48#
```

Comment: I would personally use loop-protect in addition to spanning tree, rather than instead of it; with that the forwarding delay will protect your network. With loop-protect you are reduced to damage limitation after the fact. If you set a broadcast limit that might stop the ports saturating with junk and let the loop-protect packets through - I've not tried that though.

Comment: Spanning Tree is not an option. The Network contains Switches from different Vendors and Spanning Tree is not compatible enough. I will test your Broadcast Limit Idea.

Comment: @CookieCrash Amazing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved the Problem by follow the hint from [richardb](https://serverfault.com/users/228337/richardb). 
How i have done this:

1. Set Broadcast Limit to 30%
2. Setting up loop-protect for all Ports

All loops are detected from now.

Answer (score 6):

> Spanning Tree is not an option. The Network contains Switches from different Vendors and Spanning Tree is not compatible enough.

[image: what year is it?]

If your switches don't at least support [MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol#Multiple_Spanning_Tree_Protocol) which has been around for almost 10 years now, replace [that garbage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dHqmm.jpg). Disabling spanning tree is the most incorrect solution to the problem.